# Webpack does not generate/recreate dist/vendor.css

Tags: angular, webpack, aspnetcoretemplatepack

I have an angular2+ project I created using the aspnet core template. I Started the project using the template provided by asp net core. I've updated the packages since to Angular 5.1.
I recently got a new laptop so I did a clone on the new machine however when I run webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js it doesnt generate the vendor.css and it throws this error:
[image]

This is my webpack.config.vendor.js which I barely changed:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: [ '.js' ] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        entry: {
            vendor: [
                '@angular/animations',
                '@angular/common',
                '@angular/compiler',
                '@angular/core',
                '@angular/forms',
                '@angular/http',
                '@angular/platform-browser',
                '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
                '@angular/router',
                'bootstrap',
                'es6-shim',
                'es6-promise',
                'event-source-polyfill',
                'jquery',
                'zone.js'
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: '/dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
                $: 'jquery', 
                jQuery: 'jquery', 
                jquery: 'jquery' 
            }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        target: 'node',
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist'),
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [ { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] } ]
        },
        entry: { vendor: ['aspnet-prerendering'] },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ]
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
}
```

The project that I have in my previous machine does have the vendor.css.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who has the similar problem when updating from Angular4.x to 5.x I just had to add this:

```
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)esm5/, path.join(__dirname, './src')),
```

in the plugins

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks good. May the vendor modules are upgraded and doesnt `require` css anymore ?

Couple of things to check for

1. Make sure your new laptop has got the **exact same versions** of the
   vendor modules as that of the old machine.
2. From application side,
   remove the reference to `vendor.css` and see if there are any issues
   in UI.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, but it seems the webpack.vendor is obsolete/broken(as I dont know it deeply enough Im not sure) when I updated it since angular4.2 to 5.0... see fix below